# Sum of certain columns is wrong after using pd.wide_to_long?

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is: sum of columns which starts with Medium (5+7) not 12 as well the remaining columns which starts Lower and Upper using `pd.wide_to_long` and only shows the first sum i.e sum-Md.

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Date  Medium-Ab  Lower-B.c   Upper-Dd  Medium-Fb  Lower-Gc Upper-H.I  year
09/2022          5          3         10          7         4        12  2022
10/2022          8          4         12          9         6        14  2022
11/2022          9          6         14         10         9        16  2022
12/2022         15         14         20          5         4        18  2022
01/2023         17         13         25         13         8        12  2023 
    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...       ...  ...
12/2023         16         11         24         16        12        19  2023
01/2024         27         23         35         33        28        42  2023 
    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...       ...   ...
12/2024         10         11         14         16        12        19  2023
    ...        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...       ...  ...
12/2032        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...       ...  ...
```

What I want is:

```
   Date  Medium-Ab  Lower-B.c  Upper-Dd  Medium-Fb  Lower-Gc  Upper-H.I  year  sum-Md sum-Lo  sum-Up
09/2022          5          3        10          7         4         12  2022      12      7      22 
10/2022          8          4        12          9         6         14  2022     ...    ...     ...
11/2022          9          6        14         10         9         16  2022     ...    ...     ...
    ...        ...        ...       ...        ...       ...        ...   ...     ...    ...     ...
11/2022        ...        ...       ...        ...       ...        ...   ...     ...    ...     ...
```

My try is:

```
df['sum-Md','sum-Lo','sum-Up'] = (
   pd.wide_to_long(
       df, stubnames=["Medium", 'Lower', 'Upper'],
       i=["Date",], j="zone",
       sep="-", suffix='\w+'
   )
   .query("year>=2022", engine="python")
   .groupby("Date")
   .Medium
   .sum()
   .array
)
```

Comment: I don't know why the dataframe is shown in one line if anyone could correct that wrong showing I will be happy

Comment: Thanks, Timus , could you guide me to do what you did to reformat my question as I am new in Pandas.

Comment: You can click  on the `edited ...` part to see what was adjusted. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76304949/revisions) the link to the view you'll get. If you want to show a dataframe then one way would be to print it to the console, copy the result, an paste it into the question (with ````none ...```` code fences). Hint: If you want that someone gets allerted the you need use the @ in front of the handle, like @Timus.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: Do you just want to sum up the resp. columns to get the result: For example `Medium-Ab` and `Medium-Fb` to get `sum-Md`? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Thank @Timus . Yes I want sum up Medium-Ab and Medium-Fb in a new column its name sum-Md as well as Lower columns in a new column its name sum-Lo and Upper columns in a new column sum-Up then append the new three columns to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand

> Yes I want sum up Medium-Ab and Medium-Fb in a new column its name sum-Md as well as Lower columns in a new column its name sum-Lo and Upper columns in a new column sum-Up then append the new three columns to the original dataframe.

correctly, then the most straight-forward and explicit way to do that would be:

```py
df['sum-Md'] = df['Medium-Ab'] + df['Medium-Fb']
df['sum-Lo'] = df['Lower-B.c'] + df['Lower-Gc']
df['sum-Up'] = df['Upper-Dd'] + df['Upper-H.I']
# Part in comment
df['Medium-Ab'] = df['Medium-Ab'] / df['sum-Md']
df['Medium-Fb'] = df['Medium-Fb'] / df['sum-Md']
df['Lower-B.c'] = df['Lower-B.c'] / df['sum-Lo']
df['Lower-Gc'] = df['Lower-Gc'] / df['sum-Lo']
df['Upper-Dd'] = df['Upper-Dd'] / df['sum-Up']
df['Upper-H.I'] = df['Upper-H.I'] / df['sum-Up']
```

If the dataframe has actually more columns of the sort then you could try more programatically approaches like

```py
for start, short in ('Medium', 'Md'), ('Lower', 'Lo'), ('Upper', 'Up'):
    col, cols = f'sum-{short}', [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith(start)]
    df[col] = df[cols].sum(axis=1)
    # Part in comment
    df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[col].values, axis=0)
```

or

```py
df[['sum-Md','sum-Lo','sum-Up']] = (
    df.drop(columns=['Date', 'year'])
    .groupby(lambda c: c.split('-')[0], axis=1, sort=False)
    .sum()
)
# Part in comment
for start, short in ('Medium', 'Md'), ('Lower', 'Lo'), ('Upper', 'Up'):
    base = f'sum-{short}'
    for col in df.filter(regex=f'^{start}').columns:
        df[col] = df[col] / df[base]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Timus. Both codes are very useful. Could you guide me to  divide columns which starts Medium by sum-Md as well as columns which starts Lower by sum-Lo and columns which starts Upper by sum-up then put these new columns in a new dataframe if you don't mind.

Comment: @sazaki I don't quite understand: Do you only want to have the columns `Medium-Ab`, `Lower-B.c`, `Upper-Dd`, `Medium-Fb`, `Lower-Gc`, `Upper-H.I `, `sum-Md`, `sum-Lo`, and `sum-Up` in the result dataframe?

Comment: @ Timus,I mean a new dataframe composed of the following columns: Medium-Ab / sum-Md , Medium-Fb / sum-Md  , Lower-B.c/sum-Lo, Lower-Gc/sum-Lo , Upper-Dd/sum-Up, Upper-H.I/sum-Up , sum-Md, sum-Lo, and sum-Up .

Comment: @sazaki I have added this part the answer (the parts starting with `# Part in comment`.

Comment: Thanks @Timus , your code is very useful and provides me what I want.